# OLS regression in javascript with t test

Tags: javascript, linear-regression

Couldn't find a package that computes multiple variable linear regression with t test statistics and p values

The dream is something like python statemodels.summary like this:

(The final aim is to use it as a bigquery js udf)

[image]